# Extra padding showing between WindowTitleBar and Toolbar on Lollipop and later versions when Fragment replace

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I couldn't remove the padding above toolbar

[image: Screenshot 1: Padding in Android Lollipop and later versions]

But there is no such issue on below Lollipop devices

[image: Screenshot 2: No padding in earlier versions]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@xml/drop_shadow_bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

next_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_textcontents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/aet_post_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_post_title"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">

            <requestFocus />
        </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_grey" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/aet_post_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/post_description"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And how we suppose to know which codes you are using? And how we should help you ? At least, Please add some layout codes...

Comment: Sure! i've updated the Qn with layout codes. I'm getting a white padding between title bar and actionbar, but this works in lower versions (<21). check those 2 screenshots I need to remove that, can you help?

Comment: Sure! We're here to help right? :) Please just let us know ; **The image you've uploaded** is in the `Fragment` or it's in the `Main Activity`? i said that because there is a back button up there and it doesn't sounds like `MainActivity` which you've uploaded the layout codes...

Comment: Images are of Fragments. Main activity have a separate placeholder fragment. Then I replaced this placeholderfragment with the above fragment. Note that:- placeholder fragment doesnt have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get rid of it. If you want in your XML code the parent element should have padding-bottom,up, right, left. Although you have not really asked a question. I am assuming you ask why did it change. You can find all the material about android application design posted by google in the following link: [google material design](https://material.io/guidelines/) Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting a white padding between title bar and actionbar, but this works in lower versions (<21). check those 2 screenshots I need to remove that, can you help?